# Alternatives to LEAD and LAG in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need to find an alternative to LAG and LEAD for finding the previous and next entry in my table in SQLite since those are not support in the version used (updating is not an option).
But I also cant use the value I order by, since it can be a date and therefore can be identical on multiple entries.
Since the table has to be sorted by date, using the ID isn't an option either.

It'd be great if someone knew an alternative way of dealing with this issue, since after more than an hour of searching and trying I am out of ideas.

Edit:

The important columns to my use case are:

```
_id     booking_date
  1       2017:11-21
  3       2017:11-21
  4       2017:11-21
  5       2017:11-21
  2       2017:11-22
  6       2017:11-22
  7       2017:11-22
...
```

_id is the primary key.
The bookings need to be sorted by date.
It is possible for multiple bookings to have the same date.
Bookings with the same date are sorted by their ids (See id 2, 6 and 7 in the give n example)

I need a way to query the entry before and after an entry by its id.

For example for _id=6 the I need a query that selects the row with _id=2 and a query that selects the row with _id=7.
Alternatively a query single query that selects both will work just as good.

I do not need you to provide an entire query, but rather an approach to this issue.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  In order to use `lead()`/`lag()`, your table would need a stable ordering anyway.  What keys provide the stable ordering?

Comment: I hope the further info and example provided are of use.

Comment: . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You are not even using `_id` for the ordering, so your question cannot be answered with the data you have provided.

Comment: In the actual table the _id of course is for ordering. But the table represents Bookings. Each booking having an id, a date representing the time of execution for that booking [NOT the time of creation] and all values associated with the booking, which are unimportant for this task. when showing a list of bookings it makes sense to order the bookings by date not by id. But in order to only query the previous booking one could not just use the date since there can be multiple bookings per date. But there actually is a solution to this, you apparently didn't think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like that, this retrieves previous and next id of a given record using your sort order (by date+id) - assumming that `id` is the primary key, you can retrieve other columns od prev-next records using these ids:

```
SELECT *,
      (SELECT id FROM t t1
       WHERE t1.booking_date < t.booking_date
          OR t1.booking_date = t.booking_date AND t1.id < t.id
       ORDER BY booking_date DESC, ID DESC LIMIT 1 ) prev_id,
      (SELECT id FROM t t1
       WHERE t1.booking_date > t.booking_date
          OR t1.booking_date = t.booking_date AND t1.id > t.id
       ORDER BY booking_date , ID  LIMIT 1 ) next_id 
FROM t
order by booking_date, id
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/17631/2

```
| id | booking_date | prev_id | next_id |
|----|--------------|---------|---------|
|  1 |   2017-11-21 |  (null) |       3 |
|  3 |   2017-11-21 |       1 |       4 |
|  4 |   2017-11-21 |       3 |       5 |
|  5 |   2017-11-21 |       4 |       2 |
|  2 |   2017-11-22 |       5 |       6 |
|  6 |   2017-11-22 |       2 |       7 |
|  7 |   2017-11-22 |       6 |  (null) |
```

Comment: Clever answer and way to do it LAG-free. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the table looked like this, the final select would be fairly trivial.

```
_id     booking_date   seq
  1       2017:11-21    1
  3       2017:11-21    2
  4       2017:11-21    3
  5       2017:11-21    4
  2       2017:11-22    1
  6       2017:11-22    2
  7       2017:11-22    3
```

`seq` being the number of rows in the same booking_date with smaller id. You could create a virtual view  with this structure to drive the main select.

This is a possible approach. Since you were not soliciting "an entire query", I leave it up to you how to implement this idea.

Comment: But since it doesn't look like this, this answer isn't helpful at all, is it?

Comment: @Jujinko You owe me an upvote. Notice the last line `You could create a virtual view with this structure to drive the main select. `. In other words, create a structure that _does_ look like this.  I did, in fact, create a repro, but  the OP wanted an "approach" not "an entire query". Thanks for explaining the downvote and giving me the opportunity to rebut and clarify my answer.